# How to do load testing that simulate adding a node with a drupal site?

Tags: testing

I know we can use apaceh workbench to do some load testing and provide some statistics. However, how would I go about finding out how many logged in users can perform certain action (adding a node, comment, or submitting a custom form)?
An idea was that to create a script that perform the action and use apache workbench to execute the script.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script that does the stuff that you want logged in users to be able to perform, then run `ab` against it:

```
ab -n <no: of requests> -c <concurrency> http://mysite.com/user_action.php
```

One thing you could do is have user_action perform various actions in random. So each time ab hits it, it might to a node creation, or a form submit or a comment entry etc..This would simulate a closer scenario to real world actions.